# Power BI Web.Contents credentials problem

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am running a function to import data from Excel spreadsheets.  It begins with something like

```
 Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents(pathName))
```

with the pathName being passed as a parameter such as "https://spo.domain.com/sites/long_path_name/file_name.xlsx"

So far, so good.  It's working fine in PowerBI desktop but when trying to use it in a Dataflow I get the error message of "One or More tables references a dynamic data source".  Fair enough, I've modified the above to

```
 Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents("https://spo.domain.com",[RelativePath="sites/long_path_name/file_name.xlsx"]))
```

The only problem is that using the latter doesn't allow me to authenticate using my normal credentials.  For some reason, using

```
 Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents("https://spo.domain.com/sites/long_path_name/file_name.xlsx"))
```

works fine, but using

```
 Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents("https://spo.domain.com/",[RelativePath="sites/long_path_name/file_name.xlsx"]))
```

Does not work.  What am I missing?